# Interaction with Market app is causing window focus errors

Tags: android, android-intent, google-play

I have a strange problem, I am wanting to launch to the marketplace from my app - am doing the following.

```
 Intent marketIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(
             "market://details?id=" + activity.getPackageName()));

    try {
        activity.startActivity(marketIntent);
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
        Toast.makeText(activity, "Could not launch market", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

However when there the user can press `Open` again, when they do that I get :

```
08-22 15:18:37.510: INFO/ActivityManager(260): Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 pkg=com.xyz.appname cmp=com.xyz.appname/.mainapp } from pid 22853
08-22 15:18:37.590: INFO/ActivityManager(260): Starting: Intent { cmp=com.xyz.appname/.secondactivity } from pid 25735
08-22 15:18:37.590: WARN/InputManagerService(260): Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@2b49a938
```

and it never reopens the app , they just stuck there - hitting back does work.
Tracing the code the warning is coming from this in `mainapp` :

```
Intent tabActivity = new Intent();
    tabActivity.setClass(this, secondactivity.class);
startActivity(tabActivity);
this.finish();
```

Comment: If I launch market and choose my app and press open it works 100% of the time, it only goes wrong if market was launched as an intent from my application causing some strange type of bond.

Answer (score 0):

This definitely looks like an issue with how it is restarted - you're on the right track with that last bit of code.

This flag looks like what you need to tell Android to pull the existing activity off of the history stack and re-use it:

```
FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP
```

Alternatively (if you want to restart rather than resume), maybe you could hint to Android to recycle the activity after you move on, by using this with your intent:

```
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
```